# How animate a slide off the screen when pressing next slide button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video slider on a page I am working on, but I would like a nice animation to occur when changing slides rather than just changing to the next slide. For example, animate the slide off the side of the screen and the next slide in from the other side.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
  showDivs(slideIndex);

  function plusDivs(n) {
     showDivs(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showDivs(n) {
     var i;
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
     if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
     if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
     x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  }
```

```html
<div class="video__container" style="display: flex; display: -webkit-flex; flex-direction: row; -webkit-flex-direction: row;">
   <div class="arrow__container">
    <div class="video__container--arrow arrow__back" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
     <img class="img__full" src="css/images/template_arrow.svg">
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <div class="video__container--item">
    <!-- Must include data-id, data-bg and optional video name -->
    <div class="video__slide mySlides">
     <div class="youtube-container template-youtube-container">
         <div class="youtube-player" data-id="bqlzoxTvOkE" data-bg="css/images/pb/video1.jpg"><span class="video-name">Branding</span></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video__slide mySlides">
     <div class="youtube-container template-youtube-container">
         <div class="youtube-player" data-id="S-sJp1FfG7Q" data-bg="css/images/pb/video2.jpg"><span class="video-name">UX Design</span></div>
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="video__slide mySlides">
     <div class="youtube-container template-youtube-container">
         <div class="youtube-player" data-id="zVntJ21thpQ" data-bg="css/images/pb/video3.jpg"><span class="video-name">UI Design</span></div>
     </div>
      </div>

   </div>
   
   <div class="arrow__container">
    <div class="video__container--arrow arrow__next" onclick="plusDivs(1)">
       <img class="img__full" src="css/images/template_arrow.svg">
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't have the time for a real (working) answer but a common method is to make `.video__container--item` 3x the size of the viewport (in this case because there are 3 slides) and absolutely position it to `left: -(viewport/3)`. Then, animate the position of `.mySlides` within.

Comment: Thanks @Will appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, yeah, it's a lot, but what we are doing here is avoiding JavaScript easing animations. If you do want to use easing use the following link, because I can't explain it as well as this does.
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/introduction_to_easing_in_javascript.htm
If you still want to skip the whole learning process of easing (like me) there is a way around it. 
I'll give you the short version, and if you're still confused I have a nice, long example. First, you have to make a div container to hold your slides. Basically, you are going to use JavaScript function to assign a class to that container. You'll make two for every slide except for the first and last (one to go forward, one to go back). When you're doing this, make sure to reset the animation by assigning another class to act as a null, or else... Those classes you just made will hold the animations, except in the null class. Add your animations, some styling, and html, making sure to include a button with the function from earlier. Mine is really basic, but you can really decorate it however you want.

```js
/*This is the Javascript. What we are doing here is bypassing the complexity of
Javascript animations and instead changing the class of what we want to move.
This allows us to still use the onclick function in our html, while at 
the same time using css3 animations*/
function magicbtnf() {
  document.getElementById('container').className = "magicslide";
}

function magicbtnb() {
  document.getElementById('container').className = "magicslide2";
}
```

```css
/*This is css. Most of it is styling, but I will point out importants in 
comments.*/

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "century gothic", "Arial";
  font-size: 18px;
}

#container {
  /*This is the container, make it 100% x the number of slides you have.
 This will allow each slide to fill 100% of the screen*/
  width: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
}

#container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#slide1 {
  /* You can insert your first slide CSS in here , just make sure the width
 is 1/the amount of slides you have. % is recommended, but I'm sure there
 is a way to use vw.*/
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.magicslide {
  /*This is one of two classes for the animation. We will use javascript to
 set and unset the classes to the slides*/
  -webkit-animation: switch 4s 1;
  -o-animation: switch 4s 1;
  -moz-animation: switch 4s 1;
  animation: switch 4s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-moz-keyframes switch {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes switch {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes switch {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 0px
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes switch {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 0px
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}

.notsomagic {
  /*This is basically a void element. This resets the animation so when
 you go back a slide, you can continue again.*/
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#slide2 {
  /*Same thing here as the earlier slide!*/
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.magicslide2 {
  /*This is the same animation sequence as before, but backwards*/
  -webkit-animation: switchb 4s 1;
  -o-animation: switchb 4s 1;
  -moz-animation: switchb 4s 1;
  animation: switchb 4s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes switchb {
  0% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -40%
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes switchb {
  0% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -40%
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes switchb {
  0% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -40%
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes switchb {
  0% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -40%
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--This is just some boring old html. It's esentially placing everything where it needs to go. The most noticable part is the input, which states our function from the javascript onclick -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Slide</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="change_slides.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="change_slides.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="slide1">
      Hello! This is my slideshow!
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="change" value="Click Me!" onclick="magicbtnf()">
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
      This is slide #2!
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="change2" value="Click Me Too!" onclick="magicbtnb()">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you don't feel like making your own animations, there are free downloads. I recommend Animate.css. It come chalked full of really smooth animations, and with a couple quick edits, you can make them work really well with your slideshow. The link is: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ 
I hope this helps! :D

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help.